# Tightness of a sequence of random variables with bounded mean and variance

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Suppose that $X_1, X_2, X_3,\ldots$ are real–valued random variables having means $\mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3, \ldots $ and standard deviations $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3, \ldots$ and suppose that $|\mu_n|$ and $\sigma_n$ are bounded sequences. Show that the collection $(X_n)$ is tight.

I was wondering how to prove it. I want to use the Chebyshev’s
inequality but I am sure how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Approach 1:** Since the sequence $(\mu_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, it follows from the triangle inequality that

$$\{|X_n| \geq R\} \subseteq \{|X_n-\mu_n| \geq R/2\}$$

for $R \gg 1$ sufficiently large. Hence, by the Tschebyscheff inequality

$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq R) \leq \frac{4}{R^2} \mathbb{E}(|X_n-\mu_n|^2) = \frac{4}{R^2} \sigma_n^2.$$

As $(\sigma_n^2)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, this shows the tightness of $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

---

**Approach 2:** As @Did suggested, there is also the possibility to use the identity

$$\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \mathbb{E}((X-\mathbb{E}X)^2)+\mathbb{E}(X)^2$$

which implies, by Markov's inequality,

$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq R) \leq \frac{1}{R^2} \mathbb{E}(X_n^2) = \frac{\sigma_n^2+\mu_n^2}{R^2}.$$

Because of the boundedness of $(\mu_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(\sigma_n^2)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ this entails the tightness of the sequence.

Comment: That, or simply, $$\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \geq R) \leqslant \frac{\mu_n^2+\sigma_n^2}{R^2}$$

Comment: @Did Yeah...but I'm not sure whether this is really that much easier to show; in the end, I think, it's a matter of personal preference (an application of the triangle inequality vs. expanding a square).

Comment: Mmmh, $E(X^2)=E(X)^2+\sigma^2(X)$ is rather more basic than everything else here, it seems.

Comment: @Did So this identity is more basic than triangle inequality? Not sure about that. Anyway, I think that the inequality $$\mathbb{P}(|X| \geq R) \leq \mathbb{P} \left( |X-\mu| \geq \frac{R}{2} \right)$$ is good to know since there are plenty of inequalities (e.g. maximal inequalities) for centered random variables. (For instance, this inequality is useful to prove the Feller property of certain processes...  obviously, this is much beyond what the OP is asking, but nevertheless I believe that this inequality is useful and worth noticing.)