# If the moments of a sequence of distributions converge, do they represent a probability?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-problem

Assume ${\bf x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ denotes a real-valued and bounded random variable. Then, the moments of $\bf x$ uniquely define its distribution.

Assume we have not only one distribution, but a sequence indexed by $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $M_{k,n}$ denote the $k$-th mixed moment of the $n$-th distribution.

If the limit

$~\lim_{n\to\infty} M_{k,n}=M_{k}$

exists for all $k$, can we conclude that the $M_{k}$ are the moments of a distribution?

Comment: Does your moment condition imply tightness? (I don't know.)

Comment: @Lorenzo Najt: I'm not familiar with tightness, but the random variables are bounded and each moment sequence is bounded. Does this imply tightness? [Do you mean the same thighness as here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053276/tightness-of-a-sequence-of-random-variables-with-bounded-mean-and-variance).

Comment: Yeah, that looks helpful. Tightness implies that there is a weakly convergent subsequence by Prokhorov's theorem, so you can pass to that subsequence. This isn't an argument, because convergence in distribution doesn't imply convergence in moments (although maybe all the moments converging is stronger?). Are you assuming that there is a universal bound, say N, for the sequence of random variables? If so, I think you can apply the portmanteau theorem with a bounded continuous function that agrees with $X^k$ on $|x| \leq N$ to get your desired conclusion.

Comment: @Lorenzo Najt: Yes, I assume a universal bound $N$ for the sequence of random variables.

Comment: Okay. So I think the answer is yes, based on the argument in that comment. Does it seem clear to you?

Comment: @Lorenzo Najt: Still difficult to grasp as I'm no so familiar with measure theory. Maybe if you spend a few words and formulate it as an answer. This would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the 1-d version of proposition that the question is looking for, which I believe to be correct (but idk for sure):

Proposition: Suppose that $X_n \in \mathbb{R}$ is a sequence of random variables such that:

- $|X_n| \leq N$
- $\lim E[X_n^k] = m_k \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $k = 1, \ldots, \infty$

Then there is a random variable $X$ with $E[X^k] = m_k$.

Proof:

<s>First, we observe that the sequence of random variables $X_n$ is tight, using: [Tightness of a sequence of random variables with bounded mean and variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053276/tightness-of-a-sequence-of-random-variables-with-bounded-mean-and-variance) .</s>

Since you are assuming the random variables are universally bounded, they are [tight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures).

By [Prokohorov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov%27s_theorem) (in particular the corollary for measures in $\mathbb{R}^m$), tightness implies that there is a subsequence $X_{n_k}$ which converges in distribution to some random variable $X$. We can pass to this subsequence, since this does not effect the two hypothesis.

Now, for any $k \geq 1$, let $f_k(x)$ be any function that agrees with $x^k$ on $[-N, N]$ and which is bounded and continuous. For instance, $f(x)$ might linearly interpolate so that it is zero on $(\infty, -N - 1) \cup (N + 1, \infty)$.

Since we have $X_n \to X$ weakly, we have from the [Portmanteau theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) that $E [ f_k(X_n) ] \to E[f(X)]$. But since $|X_n| \leq N$ and $|X| \leq N$ a.s. (this is a consequence of weak convergence, e.g. using the CDF), we have that $f_k(x) = x^k$ on $[-N, N]$, which means that $E[X_n^k] \to E[X^k]$. By the second assumption, this implies that $E[X^k] = m_k$, which is the desired conclusion. QED

Hope this helps!

I think it should be relatively straightforward to adapt to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

We don't have to worry about tightness because of your assumption about the universal boundedness:  <s>You just want to make sure you that your assumption about moments again implies tightness -- I'm not completely sure what mixed moments you are controlling, but if you get control over the first two moments of $||X_n||_2$ (or $L_p$ norms for some $p$), you can prove that the $||X_n||_2$ are tight, which implies that $X_n$ are.</s>

(I'm not sure that controlling moments like $E[X_1^k X_2^k]$ is enough; e.g. its possible that $X_1$ blows up a lot for small $X_2$, and maybe mass can escape to infinity that way? But if you know that all moments of the form $E[X_i^k]$ have limits I think you are in good shape.)

Comment: Why did you cross out (strike through) part of the  text: Did you want another text effect? Or doesn't it show up in your browser.

Comment: I was crossing it out because it was something we were discussing that is no longer relevant when you require the random variables to be universally bounded. If it's confusing feel free to ignore it.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thanks a lot for your help, I learned a lot! I'll give you a bounty of 50 for all your work, but in two days when this option is enabled.

Comment: @Its_me There's no need, save your reputation so you can get access to more site features. :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway!!

Comment: @Its_me Glad I was able to help. Do be sure to check the details of the argument. Btw, you might be interested in this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem

Comment: In fact I think the theorem there about positive definiteness of the Hankel matrices of moments might give another and probably stronger proof, since positive semi-definiteness will be closed under limits... however it seems to be about measures, and not probability measures, so maybe not...